# SQOOP to HIVE in Parquet

Tags: parquet, sqoop

SQOOP is not able to create a hive table in PARQUET format.

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sqoop_practice --username root --password hortonworks1 -m 1 --delete-target-dir --target-dir /user/hduser/sqoop/import_customer --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --fetch-size 1000 --table customer --fields-terminated-by '~' --hive-import --hive-database hivepractice --hive-table customer_parquet --as-parquetfile;

Error: Caused by: MetaException(message:Table hivepractice.customer_parquet failed strict managed table checks due to the following reason: Table is marked as a managed table but is not transactional.)

Comment: distribution: HDP 3.0.1.0-187, SQOOP - Sqoop 1.4.7.3.0.1.0-187, HIVE - Hive 3.1.0.3.0.1.0-187

Comment: In ORC,  'transactional'='true' is added and table gets created.